# Questioned while in transit in Vancouver

Tags: visas, transit, canada, vancouver

Eleven years ago, I was travelling to my country with layover at Vancouver. There, I was questioned because I did not have a transit visa.

This year, I am planning to visit some friends in Canada.
I am a permanent resident of the US.

Will that earlier event of questioning in Vancouver affect my entry, now as visitor of Canada?
Will I be allowed to enter into Canada?

Comment: You were questioned, but were you ultimately allowed to continue your travels?

Comment: It's prudent you are enquiring about this but a simple questioning especially that long ago is no reason to be worried. I have been grilled, extensively, once even pulled into secondary entering the USA but had no problems actually and a bit later I even got a NEXUS card (part of the Trusted Traveller program). Problems begin when you are refused entry and the real trouble starts when you get a big red deported stamp in your passport.

Answer (score 7):

US permanent residents are normally allowed to visit Canada without a visa (and even without a passport!). You will need to carry your green card with you and show it to immigration officers. But since you have had previous history with Canada, you may expect to be asked about it when you arrive. You should answer such questions truthfully. If you were not refused entry on your previous transit, you should not have any serious problem now.